# How to transfer a CSV file from Azure Data Lake/Blob Storage to PostgreSQL database with Airflow

Tags: postgresql, csv, airflow, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

devs.

I am sorry to bother you guys, but I would like to know how to transfer a CSV file from Azure Data Lake/Blob Storage to the PostgreSQL database with Airflow?

Thanks a lot,

Rodrigo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure hook you are able to do that

You will need crate a connection and configure it

Reference for Azure hook:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/_api/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/wasb/index.html

Comment: how does the solution look like with Azure Hook? I understood the OP that he wanted to transfer data from Azure Blob to Postgres via Airflow, a minimal solution should contain a method to ingest data into postgres imho.